# Error when retrieving value from the selected cell of the gridview

Tags: gridview

Here's my code. Index out of range exception is occurring every time.

string themeName =grdThemeDetails.DataKeys[e.Row.RowIndex].Values[1].ToString();

Comment: It's actually ArgumentOutOfRangeException not IndexOutOfRangeException

Comment: What happens if you use `Values[0]`?

Comment: Its picking the value of the first cell of the nested gridview. @VDWWD